# Probability Density Function of euclidean distance function

Tags: statistics

Let $X = [x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ and $Y = [y_1,\cdots,y_n]$ such that coordinates of the points be uniformly distributed in the $[-1,1]$ interval, i.e.: $x_i,y_i$ ~ $U[-1,1]$.
My problem is that of determining the probability density function of the Euclidean distance between $X$ and $Y$. Could you help me to solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplifying notation (this solution will generalize easily), lets consider the case where we are working in the square $[0,1]^2$ rather than $[0,1]^n$.

We can now conduct an experiment where we randomly select two points in the square $[0,1]^2$.

Let $f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))$ denote the probability density function of the first randomly selected point being contained in the subset $A \subset [0,1]^2$ and the second randomly selected point being contained in $B \subset [0,1]^2$.

Since $f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))$ is a probability density function on $[0,1]^2 \times [0,1]^2$ we have that:

$$P([0,1]^2 \times [0,1]^2) = \int_{[0,1]^2} \int_{[0,1]^2} f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))dV = 1$$

Since we select the points randomly, our p.d.f $f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))$ is uniform, and thus for any subset $A \times B \subset [0,1]^2 \times [0,1]^2$ we have that:

$$P(A \times B) = \int_B \int_A f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))dV$$

Let us now define a function $Z: [0,1]^2 \times [0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by:

$$Z((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2}$$

Thus $Z$ is a random variable that transforms our original sample space of $[0,1]^2 \times [0,1]^2$ into the sample space of all possible distances between the first point $(x_1,x_2)$ and the second point $(y_1,y_2)$. (Note that the codomain of a random variable is by definition $\mathbb{R}$. The range of our random variable will be the maximal distance possible between two points in the square, which is $\sqrt{2}$.)

Let $G(z)$ denote the distribution function of $Z$. Then we have that:

$G(z)= P(Z \leq z)$

$=P(\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2} \leq z)$

$= \int \int_{ \{(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2): Z((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))<z \} } f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) dV$

$=\int \int_{\{(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2): \sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2-y_2)^2} < z \}} f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2) dV$

The p.d.f g(z) of the random variable $Z$ can now be obtained by differentiation:

$g(z) = \frac{dG(z)}{dz}$

I'm new to this stuff so if somebody wants to clean this up / finish this for me that'd be great!

Comment: You can reduce the dimensionality of your integral by putting $Q_i=X_i-Y_i$ and noting $Q_1,Q_2\sim f$ are iid where $f(x)=\big[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}|x|\big]\cdot 1_{[-2,2]}$ is the pdf of the triangular distribution. So for any $z\in [0,2\sqrt{2}]$ we have $$P(Z\leq z)=\iint_{\{x^2+y^2\leq z^2\}}f(x)f(y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$ If $z\in [0,2]$ this integral is fine. On the other hand, if $z\in (2,2\sqrt{2}]$, then this is a bit nasty.

Comment: thanks everyone, could you explain what means $1_{[-2,2]}$, please @user429040

Comment: $1_{[-2,2]}$ is the indicator function of the set $[-2,2]$. As a formula, $1_{[-2,2]}(x)=1$ whenever $x\in [-2,2]$ and $1_{[-2,2]}(x)=0$ whenever $x\notin [-2,2]$

Comment: @user429040 could you help me with the generalization formula, please. I know that according https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976250/what-is-the-maximum-distance-of-k-points-in-an-n-dimensional-hypercube that the maximum distance between two points in the hypercube is $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @user429040 or what other person can help me, please? and how you obtain $z\in [0,2\sqrt{2}]$ and why $[-2,2]$ in $1_{[-2,2]}$?

Comment: In the link you provide they're referring to the "unit hypercube" which is $[0,1]^n$ and not $[-1,1]^n$. Hence maximum distance between any two points on $[-1,1]^n$ is $2\sqrt{n}$. I would help you but I don't know how to solve the problem! The integrals are in arbitrary dimensions and they're nasty even in $2D$